# Show separate tooltip(top/middle/bottom) on mouseover of upper and lower point of error amchart

Tags: amcharts

I am using error amchart so i want to show ballon(tooltip) on mouseover of top error, middle error and bottom error of each error field. Hide on mouse leave. Following is the error amchart link https://www.amcharts.com/demos/error-chart/

Comment: Can you further something for me ?:> @kometen

Comment: The above Question  "Show separate tooltip on mouseover of upper and lower point of error amchart"

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no knowledge of the product. I just saw the spelling error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding some custom code, which creates separate graphs for top and bottom error values. You will need three graphs because the chart will display only one balloon per graph.

Here's a quick "plugin" I whipped up that does that automatically:

```
/**
 * amCharts plugin: show three balloons for each error data point
 * The plugin expects "showAllBalloons" to be set to true for the graph
 * you want this to be applied to
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

  // find graphs that need to be augmented with additional balloons
  for(var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
    var g = chart.graphs[i];
    if (g.showAllBalloons === true) {
      for(var x = 0; x < chart.dataProvider.length; x++) {
        var dp = chart.dataProvider[x];
        var value = dp[g.valueField];
        var error = dp[g.errorField];
        dp[g.valueField + "Top"] = value + error / 2;
        dp[g.valueField + "Bottom"] = value - error / 2;
      }

      // add additional graph for top and bottom values
      var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
      graph.valueField = g.valueField + "Top";
      graph.lineColor = g.lineColor;
      graph.visibleInLegend = false;
      graph.lineAlpha = 0;
      chart.addGraph(graph);

      var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
      graph.valueField = g.valueField + "Bottom";
      graph.lineColor = g.lineColor;
      graph.visibleInLegend = false;
      graph.lineAlpha = 0;
      chart.addGraph(graph);
    }
  }

}, ["serial"]);
```

And here's a full working code:

```js
/**
 * amCharts plugin: show three balloons for each error data point
 * The plugin expects "showAllBalloons" to be set to true for the graph
 * you want this to be applied to
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  
  // find graphs that need to be augmented with additional balloons
  for(var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++) {
    var g = chart.graphs[i];
    if (g.showAllBalloons === true) {
      for(var x = 0; x < chart.dataProvider.length; x++) {
        var dp = chart.dataProvider[x];
        var value = dp[g.valueField];
        var error = dp[g.errorField];
        dp[g.valueField + "Top"] = value + error / 2;
        dp[g.valueField + "Bottom"] = value - error / 2;
      }
      
      // add additional graph for top and bottom values
      var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
      graph.valueField = g.valueField + "Top";
      graph.lineColor = g.lineColor;
      graph.visibleInLegend = false;
      graph.lineAlpha = 0;
      chart.addGraph(graph);
      
      var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
      graph.valueField = g.valueField + "Bottom";
      graph.lineColor = g.lineColor;
      graph.visibleInLegend = false;
      graph.lineAlpha = 0;
      chart.addGraph(graph);
    }
  }
  
}, ["serial"]);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "year": 2005,
    "value": 11.5,
    "error": 10
  }, {
    "year": 2006,
    "value": 26.2,
    "error": 5
  }, {
    "year": 2007,
    "value": 30.1,
    "error": 5
  }, {
    "year": 2008,
    "value": 29.5,
    "error": 7
  }, {
    "year": 2009,
    "value": 24.6,
    "error": 10
  } ],
  "balloon": {
    "textAlign": "left"
  },
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "id": "v1",
    "axisAlpha": 0
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "value:<b>[[value]]</b><br>error:<b>[[error]]</b>",
    "bullet": "yError",
    "bulletSize": 10,
    "lineColor": "#67b7dc",
    "errorField": "error",
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "valueField": "value",
    "bulletAxis": "v1",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "showAllBalloons": true
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "value"
  } ],
  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "cursorPosition": "mouse",
    "graphBulletSize": 1,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "year",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0
  }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure if this is what you requested.

You can use [`balloonFunction`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction) to change the text of a balloon.

```
"graphs": [ {
     "balloonFunction": function(item) {
       var data = item.dataContext;
       return "high:<b>" + (data.value + data.error)
           + "</b><br>low:<b>" + (data.value - data.error)
           + "</b><br>value:<b>" + data.value
           + "</b><br>error:<b>" + data.error + "</b>";
     }
[
```

Take a look at this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwrWpz?editors=001).

Comment: Actually  want to show three kind of values on graph. It's represented in vertical line. I want to show the real value with the Error value in the middle of the line which is currently happening. But at the top line I want to show the top value of that line according to Y-axis. And for lower end of line I want to show the value of lower line as per y-axis and want to hide all other tooltip.

Comment: You mean seperate ballons for top/"middle"/bottom? I don't know if this is possible to be honest.

Comment: Exectly the same thing which i want.@gerric